# Typescript useState error boolean has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state, react-typescript

I am using Typescript with React Native and I am having trouble with an error on the console. It says "This expression is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures."
The code is simple, it just has two cards in the home page and if the user clicks one of them, it should send the user to that page. I tried to achieve that trough useState in order to understand better the hook. This is the code in home.tsx:

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native"

import CardsComponent from "../../components/cards/cards"
import EcoNoticias from "../../components/EcoNoticias/EcoNoticias";
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export interface HomeComponentProps {
    
}
 
const HomeComponent: React.FC<HomeComponentProps> = () => {
    const [buttonPressed, setButtonPressed] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const handlePage = () => {
        setButtonPressed(true);
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Hello User</Text>
                <View>
                    {() => buttonPressed(false)} ?
                    <CardsComponent>
                        <Text style={styles.textCard}>Tips</Text>
                        <Button title='Tips' onPress={() => {}} />
                    </CardsComponent>
                    <CardsComponent>
                        <Text style={styles.textCard}>Eco-Noticias</Text>
                        <Button title='Eco-Noticias' onPress={handlePage} />
                    </CardsComponent> : <EcoNoticias />
                </View>
            </View>
        </>
    );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    title: {
        fontSize: 23,
        paddingBottom: 50,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    textCard: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: '700',
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        width: '50%',
    },
});


export default HomeComponent;
```

The error it's in the if ternario, line 24: "buttonPressed(false)".

Comment: Shouldn't it be `setButtonPressed(false)`?

Comment: Do you mean in the function handlePage? I want it true so, when the user clicks the button goes to that page.

Comment: What does `{() => buttonPressed(false)} ?` statement do?

Comment: fi it is false, shows the card component with its content, and if it is true shows the EcoNoticias component

Comment: Sounds like you meant to do `{buttonPressed === false ?` or `{!buttonPressed ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{() => buttonPressed(false)} ?
```

This line says to switch back to plain javascript (as opposed to jsx), then create a function with the text `() => buttonPressed(false)`, then switch back to jsx and put the string "?" on the screen. The typescript error your getting is pointing out that since `buttonPressed` is a boolean, it doesn't make sense to try to call it as a function.

From the comments, it appears what you meant to do was this:

```
{buttonPressed === false ? (
  <React.Fragment>
    <CardsComponent>
      <Text style={styles.textCard}>Tips</Text>
      <Button title="Tips" onPress={() => {}} />
    </CardsComponent>
    <CardsComponent>
      <Text style={styles.textCard}>Eco-Noticias</Text>
      <Button title="Eco-Noticias" onPress={handlePage} />
    </CardsComponent>
  </React.Fragment>
) : (
  <EcoNoticias />
)}
```

The `<React.Fragment>` is necessary, because you want to have multiple elements. If you prefer, you can use the shorthand `<></>` instead of `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`